# Can somebody tell me how to download patches for RHEL that I can burn to disc?

Tags: linux, rhel5

How would I go about downloading the patches from somewhere without actually installing them so that I can burn them to disc and install them on machines that don't have any internet connectivity?

Answer (score 4):

The official answer is to talk to Redhat Enterprise support and they'll hook you up.

Since there's a decent chance that you might be running a RHEL system without support (and a RHEL system without support is actually less useful than CentOS), if this is the case, you might as well convert it to a CentOS machine:

http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/documentations-a-howto/213-how-to-jul-convert-rhel-5-to-centos-5

Answer (score 2):

First, I agree with Matt's answer:if you have support, contact them.  Without support, might as well be doing CentOS.  But, going in a different direction than Matt's answer.  If you actually have support, but are sitting behind a firewall that doesn't allow outbound connections to do the updates, I can think of 2 options:

1) RHN - You should be able to login to RHN and browse to Channels, then to the specific channel(x86_64 for example), then packages and get a list of all the packages that are available.  Once you click on the actual package, you'll get a "download package" option.

2) Another System - If you have another RedHat box that is able to get to the internet, you can download the package there and copy it to your destination system as well.  Assuming RHEL5 with the downloadonly plugin, you can run "yum --downloadonly install whateverpackages", which will download all the packages specified to /var/cache/yum/..., then you can copy the contents from there.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have the appropriate support form Red Hat, you could setup the one machine with external access to be an RHN Satellite, pointing your internal machines to it as their repository.

http://www.redhat.com/red_hat_network/